# Python Pandas do an operation over a set of different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple text columns and some values, id like to group the results of an operation in the way "set of the same A,B and C" for making a ridge regresion between q and value, and i'm sure there is a better way to do this with built in functions but i haven't got the answer yet.

```
ID   A      B    C    q    value
1    Day    N    Wed  20    30
2    Noon   N    Wed  12    50
3    Day    S    Mon  30    13
4    Night  W    Sun  5      6
5    Night  E    Sun  20    20
6    Day    S    Wed  40    20
              ...
```

I want to make a regresion over q and value over the different [A,B,C] combinations

```
for uniqueA in df['A'].unique():
    for uniqueB in df.query('A == @uniqueA')['B'].unique():
        for uniqueC in df.query('A== @uniqueA and B == @uniqueB')['C'].unique():
            aux = df.query('A== @uniqueA and B == @uniqueB and C == @uniqueC')[['A','B','C','q',value]]
            aux = aux.groupby(['A','B','C','q'])['value'].sum().reset_index()
            # Make a regression on [x,y] ([q, value]) and save prediction results on a dataframe
```

The problem is on performance as they are a good amount of columns and rows data and nesting "for"s don't seems to be a good solution

Comment: What is your expected result? Your code has invalid indentation and uses an undefinded variable *value*. You're assigning *aux* twice, but never use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = df.apply(lambda r: r['q'] * r['value'] if r['value'] < 30 else r['q'] * r['value'] /2, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do so.

One way is using [**df.loc**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) method:

```
condition = df['q'] < 30 # condition

df.loc[condition, "ans"]  = df['q'] * df['value']     # when true
df.loc[~condition, "ans"] = df['q'] * df['value'] / 2 # when false
```

Another way is using **[Numpy's where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)** method:

```
import numpy as np
df['ans'] = np.where(df['q']<30, df['q'] * df['value'], df['q'] * df['value'] / 2)
```

The syntax so you understand what's happening is

```
np.where(condition, operation when true, operation when false)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a vectorised operation you can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), which returns an array:

```
import numpy as np

np.where(df['value'].lt(30),
         df['q'].mul(df['value']), 
         df['q'].mul(df['value']).div(2))

Out[162]: array([300., 300., 390.,  30., 400., 800.])
```

- [`lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html)
- [`mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html)
- [`div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html)

---

To assign your result back to a new column in your existing dataframe:

```
df['result'] = np.where(df['value'].lt(30),
         df['q'].mul(df['value']), 
         df['q'].mul(df['value']).div(2))
>>> df

   ID      A  B    C   q  value  result
0   1    Day  N  Wed  20     30   300.0
1   2   Noon  N  Wed  12     50   300.0
2   3    Day  S  Mon  30     13   390.0
3   4  Night  W  Sun   5      6    30.0
4   5  Night  E  Sun  20     20   400.0
5   6    Day  S  Wed  40     20   800.0
```